# rangeOfString: always returns the same range for a recurring character

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I would like to get an `NSRange` for each group in an `NSString`, separated by whitespace.

I currently have this:

```
self.statement1String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"??? = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4"];

for (NSString *component in [self.statement1String componentsSeparatedByString:@" "])
{
        NSRange range=[self.statement1String rangeOfString:component];
        NSLog(@"range is %@ for string %@", [NSValue valueWithRange:range], component);
}
```

Which prints out

```
2014-11-12 17:19:00.011[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {0, 3} for string ???
2014-11-12 17:19:00.012[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {4, 1} for string =
2014-11-12 17:19:00.012[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {6, 2} for string n1
2014-11-12 17:19:00.013[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {9, 1} for string +
2014-11-12 17:19:00.013[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {11, 2} for string n2
2014-11-12 17:19:00.014[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {9, 1} for string +
2014-11-12 17:19:00.015[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {16, 2} for string n3
2014-11-12 17:19:00.015[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {9, 1} for string +
2014-11-12 17:19:00.015[3606:758370] range is NSRange: {21, 2} for string n4
```

I am getting the same range for the '+' in each iteration. How can I make sure I am getting the next '+' sign in the for loop?

Comment: Sometimes it helps to read the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rangeOfString:options:range:` instead.

```
self.statement1String = @"??? = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4";

NSInteger start = 0;
for (NSString *component in [self.statement1String componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]) {
    NSRange checkRange = NSMakeRange(start, self.statementString.length - start);
    NSRange range = [self.statement1String rangeOfString:component options:0 range:checkRange];
    NSLog(@"range is %@ for string %@", NSStringFromRange(range), component);
    start = range.location + range.length;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `-rangeOfString:options:range:`, passing a range consisting of the end of the last range to the end of the string.

However, this is a job better suited to `NSScanner`.

Comment: thanks Ken, your answer is correct too, and I also appreciate the direction on the NSScanner. I will read on it. However I think I should accept rmaddy's answer as correct since he/she provided the example. Is this ok with you?